# Using styled-components with Inferno JS

Tags: reactjs, themes, styled-components, infernojs

I'm using InfernoJS as an alternative for React. Is it possible to use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) in Inferno without inferno-compat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inferno has a React-like API but doesn't try to be 100% compatible. (contrary to Preact, which works with `styled-components` out of the box)

Since `styled-components` returns React components and not Inferno components you have to use `inferno-compat`.

Comment: Thank you Max! Unfortunately, we do not use `inferno-compat` Any suggestions about other CSS-in-JS libraries which would work with Inferno ?